# pyspark - spark-submit with internal and public libraries

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I'm trying to run the following command to submit a pyspark job on EMR with my own libraries and public libraries (such as pandas and numpy):

```sh
spark-submit --deploy-mode client --py-files dependencies.zip main.py
```

The dependencies.zip has pandas library and its dependencies, and my internal library (xpto library):

```
- dependencies:
  - pandas
  - numpy
  - ...
  - xpto
     - __init__.py
     - xpto.py
```

When I start the job I receive the error: `no module named 'pandas'`.

So, How Can I pass my own libraries and public libraries within a `.zip` to run the job?